# Save result of a grep -c into a shell variable

Tags: bash, grep, bash-scripting

How can I store the result of `grep -c` as an integer in a shell variable?

This:

```
check=sudo virsh list |egrep -c '\b[0-9]{2}\b'
```

only gives me the number of matches and prints it on screen whereas the value of check is `NULL`.

If I execute :

```
check=`sudo virsh list |egrep -c '\b[0-9]{2}\b'`
```

I get an error that says

```
./test: 1 :Not found
```

where `1` is the number of matches.

Comment: I fixed your markup, since the forum code borked your code examples as they were. Note the comment on David's answer: you have probably accidentally entered a space character somewhere around the `=` sign in the second example. A minimal example is to test: `check=\`echo 1\``, which works, and then `check= \`echo 1\`` which returns `bash: 1: command not found` (or technically runs a command named "`1`" if it exists in the path).

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
check=$(sudo virsh list | egrep -c '\b[0-9]{2}\b')
```

`$(command)` behaves like a variable where the value is the output of `command`.

Comment: Note that it is very important *not* to have spaces around the `=` sign -- from the error description, it sounds like that may be part of the original problem.